# Tables have 'cells within cells' in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I don't know what this is called or how to Google for it. But somehow a couple of cells in my table seem to have sprouted new cells within them. 
[image]

[image]

These are definitely table cells, not text frames-- there's no way for me to select them individually, but when I drag the inner frame edges up or down, it resizes the whole cell. No table styles have been applied, as far as I can tell. Normally this wouldn't be a problem (the frames don't appear when I select Hide Frame Edges in the View menu), but I need to export these tables to XML, and the resulting XML is very strange.

Is there a way to remove or merge these cells so that they become just one cell (identical to the other blue cells in the photo), without having an extra frame within them?

I'm using InDesign CS6.

Comment: Put a cursor inside the middle cell and press "Esc" It should highlight the whole cell. If it's really another cell then holding "shift" use arrows to select the "mother" one and then just merge them.

Comment: When I click Escape, it selects the cell, but using Shift + any of the arrow keys does nothing. It just sits there with 'Number' highlighted. This is what it looks like: http://imgur.com/m7IFOcm

Comment: That mean it's a table inside a cell. When having the inside cell selected go to table menu and choose "change table to text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be an entire table in itself – albeit a very *small* one, just a single one row and one column.

With the text cursor inside this cell, choose "Convert Table to Text" in the Table menu. That ought to get rid of the mysterious cell.

If after selecting that menu option the entire *table* disappears and is replaced by tabbed text, then there are 2 possible scenarios: either you did not click "inside" the table-to-be-killed but just outside of it (thus selecting the 'outer' table), or this is not a table-in-a-table but something entirely else.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the issue. I did not have the problem you mentioned, I was able to simply delete the strange table without affecting the rest of it.